# I am unavailable to execute C program in CMD and powershell

Tags: c, error-code

I am running this code in powershell and I see this type of error. How can I solve this error Please help me? And Yes I have installed GCC and G++.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct myArray
{
    int total_size;
    int used_size;
    int *ptr;
};

void createArray (struct myArray * a, int tSize, int uSize){

    a->total_size = tSize;
    a->used_size = uSize;
    a->ptr = (int *)malloc(tSize * sizeof(int));
}

void show(struct myArray *a){
    for (int i = 0; i < a->used_size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", (a->ptr)[i]);
    }
    
}
int main(){
    struct myArray marks;
    createArray(&marks, 10, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

error in CMD-> Access is denied.

error message in powershell->

```
PS D:\Programming\Data Structure\1_Data Structre Using C> cd "d:\Programming\Data Structure\1_Data Structre Using C\" ; if ($?) { gcc ArrayADT.c -o ArrayADT } ; if ($?) { .\ArrayADT }
Program 'ArrayADT.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:114
 ... C\" ; if ($?) { gcc ArrayADT.c -o ArrayADT } ; if ($?) { .\ArrayADT }
   
At line:1 char:114
 ... C\" ; if ($?) { gcc ArrayADT.c -o ArrayADT } ; if ($?) { .\ArrayADT }

    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

error IMG in powershell->

[image: error]

Comment: Have you installed gcc

Comment: Please don't tag C++ on C questions. They are very different languages.

Comment: Please do not add images of plain text of links to images of plain text. Instead copy&paste the error messages directly into the question.

Comment: You are *not* using `cmd`; you are using Power Shell.

Comment: The memory `malloc()` made available is not initialized/assigned. It's an error trying to display its contents. Try `a->ptr = calloc(tSize, sizeof(int));`

Comment: Could you post how you are compiling the program to generate the exe?  Are you compiling from the command line or using make or doing something else?

Comment: running the program ->  gcc ArrayADT.c -o ArrayADT

Comment: In both cmd and PowerShell you get "acces denied". Are you sure that you have execute permissions?

Comment: besides make sure you free the allocated memory when you're done `free(marks.ptr);`

Answer (score 0):

what is this:

```
Program 'ArrayADT.exe'
```

are you trying to run a script file?

in windows, a 'ArrayADT.exe' is expected to be a compiled+linked executable.

Suggest changing the name to:

```
ArrayADT.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem got solved, just I uninstalled my Mcafee antivirus.